# Wick's theorem: From operators to fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, wick-theorem

I understand Wick's Theorem when operators are involved to be,
$$\mathcal{N}(f(a,a^\dagger) = :\!\sum\textbf{All contractions}\!:$$
But I'm getting slightly confused when this is expanded to fields, I'm struggling to find a clear explanation that goes from operators to fields. Could someone explain these steps to me?

Comment: what resource are you reading? More details on what step you're stuck on will allow us to help you more

Comment: https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/current/qft/handouts/qftwickstheorem.pdf I'm struggling to find any resources that expand from operators to fields.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a field operator rather that a field. Just expand the field operator in modes and the coefficients are your operators on which you can use Wick’s theorem.